# How can I stop XDocument from resolving my character entities

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am reading XML and manipulating the data in various ways. However, many of the XML documents contain ISO character entities. I need to **retain** these as their entity codes, but when XDocument reads the XML file, it immediately resolves the entities into their respective symbols.

How can I prevent this?

Here is a very small sample of XML with 5 entities listed in a table. I need to read the file but keep the entity codes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doc>
<table>
    <title>iso-amsa.ent</title>
    <tgroup cols="3">
        <colspec colname="col1" colwidth="0.50*"/>
        <colspec colname="col2" align="center" colwidth="0.40*"/>
        <colspec colname="col3" colwidth="2.20*"/>
        <thead>
            <row><entry><para>ISO Entity Name</para></entry><entry><para>Unicode Entity</para></entry><entry><para>Description</para></entry></row>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <row><entry><para>cularr</para></entry><entry><para>&#x21B6;</para></entry><entry><para>ANTICLOCKWISE TOP SEMICIRCLE ARROW</para></entry></row>
            <row><entry><para>curarr</para></entry><entry><para>&#x21B7;</para></entry><entry><para>CLOCKWISE TOP SEMICIRCLE ARROW</para></entry></row>
            <row><entry><para>dArr</para></entry><entry><para>&#x21D3;</para></entry><entry><para>DOWNWARDS DOUBLE ARROW</para></entry></row>
            <row><entry><para>darr2</para></entry><entry><para>&#x21CA;</para></entry><entry><para>DOWNWARDS PAIRED ARROWS</para></entry></row>
            <row><entry><para>dharl</para></entry><entry><para>&#x21C3;</para></entry><entry><para>DOWNWARDS HARPOON WITH BARB LEFTWARDS</para></entry></row>
        </tbody>
    </tgroup>
</table>
</doc>
```

This is the very simple means in which I read the file (but I have tried various ways):

```
string fileName = "C:\MyTestFile.xml";

XDocument _doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
```

As soon as the XML is read, it converts the entities to their symbols.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: It doesn't make sens ... `&#x21C3;` in XML is DOWN HARPOON WITH BARB LEFT ... if you wana `"&#x21C3;"` literal then use CDATA or any other escaping

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/sGPyR2

Comment: It suppose to.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references?force_isolation=true

Comment: What would stop you from "manually" creating the respective XML entity &#xxxx; for a given character? After all, the hex code in the entity is just the UTF-16/Unicode code point value of the character, which is the same as the ordinal value of a character in C#/.NET (because characters as represented by the `char` and `string` types in .NET are encoded in UTF-16).

Comment: Do you need to maintain the encoding in memory or do you want to only re-encode those when you output the result to a file?

Comment: None of the XML parsers I know of provide the ability to "partially parse" the document, that is, to process parts of the XML machinery while leaving other parts untouched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`XDocument` does not preserve the text encoding once the XML is loaded. The encoding is part of the base stream, not loaded XML.

If you want to re-encode those entities when you save the XML as a string, you need to use an `XmlWriter` with an `Encoding`

For example, using a `MemoryStream`

```cs
var ms = new MemoryStream();
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms, new XmlWriterSettings {Encoding = Encoding.ASCII}))
{
    _doc.Save(writer);
}
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, ms.Length));
```

Or using a `FileStream`

```cs
using (var fs = new FileStream(@"somePathHere", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(fs, new XmlWriterSettings {Encoding = Encoding.ASCII}))
{
    _doc.Save(writer);
}
```